# Audio book space adventures with Will, Kyrell, and the Professor from the 80s

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, audio-book

This is at least 35 years old, so early 80s, but my parents had some audio books on cassette for young children. The most I can remember about the stories that it featured a boy called Will who would go on galactic adventures with a girl called Kyrell and her father known as the professor.

Of the stories I can remember, the plots (loosely) involved

1. A dog with hypodermic needles for teeth and possibly in the same story, Will contracting a disease that had long been extinct.
2. Will procuring an everlasting chocolate bar at the end of one of the adventures.
3. Something involving an intergalactic football tournament.

Will was always determined to find the front door of Kyrell's house, but was never able to and always had to enter via the side entrance.

Comment: This looks like an unintentional duplicate of a question I answered in February. In brief, this is the Professor Gamma series by Fred Hoyle and Geoffrey Hoyle. OP, please take a look at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/182403/short-series-of-1980s-childrens-sf-books/260588#260588 - I've edited a link into that answer that suggests audiobook versions of the stories did indeed exist. (And my answer also mentions that "indeterminate front door!")

Comment: That's it! Thank you so much, I've been trying to figure out the name of the series for literally years!

Comment: A couple of photos of one cassette can be found on Picclick [here](https://picclick.co.uk/The-giants-of-universal-Park-science-fiction-adventures-295030201361.html) and Ebay [here](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/295030201361)